# In PHP & Composer How do I require a git repository with non standard branch name

Tags: php, git, composer-php

This is probably a stupid question:

I am trying to include the following library from github into my project.

[PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop_2.0.0)

branch name: develop_2.0.0

I would like to install it with composer and have it autoload with the rest of the libraries I am using.

The develop_ part is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Just figured it out.
Always seem to figure it out the second after I post the question.

Just prepend dev- to the branch name.

Thus: dev-develop_2.0.0