# Composer fails update on a require from git repository where branch name starts with digit and has a period

Tags: json, github, composer-php

I've forked the repository at https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm and I'm trying to add it as a require in a `composer.json` script.

My json (the relevant bits) is as follows:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/MyGHAccount/laravel-doctrine.git"
    },
.
.
.

"require": {
    .
    .
    .
    "laravel-doctrine/orm": "dev-1.2"
```

Composer generates the following error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package laravel-doctrine/orm could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

The actual branch name from https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm is `1.2`.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843446/in-php-composer-how-do-i-require-a-git-repository-with-non-standard-branch-nam) leads me to believe that Composer has no problem with periods in the branch name, but can't deal with branches starting with a digit.

I have found a workaround to this in that I simply renamed my branch on GitHub to `master`; I just want to know if there's a proper way to do this with Composer without the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**

This doesn't make sense: `https://github.com/MyGHAccount/laravel-doctrine/orm.git`.

In case you forked the original repository, the fork has another URL and not the one you posted here.

There are only two levels: `github.com/vendor/repo`.

It's possibly `https://github.com/MyGHAccount/orm.git`.

**Issue 2**

You're not using Composers verbose mode. Please use Composer's verbose mode (`-vvv`) and let Composer tell you the package resolution story and it's problems. You might be able to figure the issue out yourself.

**Issue 3**

**Before - using packagist package:**

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel-doctrine/orm": "1.2"
    }
}
```

**After - overriding with your own fork:**

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/your-account/orm"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel-doctrine/orm": "1.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I submitted the question with a typo (Issue 1); The `composer.json` file was correct, I'll update. 2: You're right I am not. I'll also do that. 3: I'm somewhat confused here. [According to the Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository), I'm supposed to prefix it with `dev-`.

Comment: I think this applies here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches.  `dev-` prefix only for named branches, not for version numbers. Try `1.2` or `1.2-dev`.